# Merging Object In Array In JavaScript if Conditions Are Met

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array-filter

I need help in merging the values of the objects in an array if the **id** is the same as the **warehouse_item_id**. In my case, there is a two objects which should be merge id: 191 and id: 52, because id 52 has warehouse_item_id of 191.
Please see the response and the code below.

> CODE

```
const yeah = yes.filter(a => a.id === a.warehouse_item_id);
```

> JSON Response

```
yes = [
  {
    "id": 191,
    "warehouse_id": 24,
    "ingredient_id": 65,
    "expiration_date": "2019-07-31",
    "available_stocks": 7,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": 65,
      "name": "erg",
      "SKU": "1000064",
      "default_unit": {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Milliliter"
      },
      "purchase_price": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 192,
    "warehouse_id": 24,
    "ingredient_id": 66,
    "expiration_date": "2019-09-18",
    "available_stocks": 33994,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": 66,
      "name": "gvf",
      "SKU": "1000065",
      "default_unit": {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Gram"
      },
      "purchase_price": 60
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 193,
    "warehouse_id": 24,
    "ingredient_id": 67,
    "expiration_date": "2019-09-19",
    "available_stocks": 43996,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": 67,
      "name": "fwefe",
      "SKU": "1000066",
      "default_unit": {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Milliliter"
      },
      "purchase_price": 70
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 52,
    "outlet_item_id": null,
    "warehouse_item_id": 191,
    "ingredient_id": 65,
    "quantity": 7,
    "total_in_lowest": 0,
    "stock_on_hand": 0,
    "adjustment_price": 0,
    "soh_total_in_lowest": 0,
    "unit_price": 50,
    "difference": 0,
    "difference_in_lowest": 0
  }
]
```

> EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
[
              {
                "id": 191,
                "warehouse_id": 24,
                "ingredient_id": 65,
                "expiration_date": "2019-07-31",
                "available_stocks": 7,
                "ingredient": {
                  "id": 65,
                  "name": "erg",
                  "SKU": "1000064",
                  "default_unit": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "name": "Milliliter"
                  },
                  "purchase_price": 50,
                  "quantity": 7,
                  "total_in_lowest": 0,
                  "stock_on_hand": 0,
                  "adjustment_price": 0,
                  "soh_total_in_lowest": 0,
                  "unit_price": 50,
                  "difference": 0,
                  "difference_in_lowest": 0
              },
              {
                "id": 192,
                "warehouse_id": 24,
                "ingredient_id": 66,
                "expiration_date": "2019-09-18",
                "available_stocks": 33994,
                "ingredient": {
                  "id": 66,
                  "name": "gvf",
                  "SKU": "1000065",
                  "default_unit": {
                    "id": 27,
                    "name": "Gram"
                  },
                  "purchase_price": 60
                }
              },
              {
                "id": 193,
                "warehouse_id": 24,
                "ingredient_id": 67,
                "expiration_date": "2019-09-19",
                "available_stocks": 43996,
                "ingredient": {
                  "id": 67,
                  "name": "fwefe",
                  "SKU": "1000066",
                  "default_unit": {
                    "id": 26,
                    "name": "Milliliter"
                  },
                  "purchase_price": 70
                }
              },
              {
                "id": 52,
                "outlet_item_id": null,
                "warehouse_item_id": 191,
                "ingredient_id": 65,
                "quantity": 7,
                "total_in_lowest": 0,
                "stock_on_hand": 0,
                "adjustment_price": 0,
                "soh_total_in_lowest": 0,
                "unit_price": 50,
                "difference": 0,
                "difference_in_lowest": 0
              }
            ]

        > EXPECTED OUTPUT
        yes = [
          {
            "id": 191,
            "warehouse_id": 24,
            "ingredient_id": 65,
            "expiration_date": "2019-07-31",
            "available_stocks": 7,
            "ingredient": {
              "id": 65,
              "name": "erg",
              "SKU": "1000064",
              "default_unit": {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Milliliter"
              },
              "purchase_price": 50
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 192,
            "warehouse_id": 24,
            "ingredient_id": 66,
            "expiration_date": "2019-09-18",
            "available_stocks": 33994,
            "ingredient": {
              "id": 66,
              "name": "gvf",
              "SKU": "1000065",
              "default_unit": {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Gram"
              },
              "purchase_price": 60
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 193,
            "warehouse_id": 24,
            "ingredient_id": 67,
            "expiration_date": "2019-09-19",
            "available_stocks": 43996,
            "ingredient": {
              "id": 67,
              "name": "fwefe",
              "SKU": "1000066",
              "default_unit": {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Milliliter"
              },
              "purchase_price": 70
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? I do not quite understand your question here.

Comment: Why do you keep asking this same question, and then removing it as soon as it gets a down vote? It is getting downvoted for a reason. E.g, please provide what debugging you have tried, and what is your expected output?

Comment: @distante. The objects which has an id = 191 and id = 52, should become one since id = 52, has a warehouse_item_id of 191. Their values should output as one object.

Comment: @Spangle. Ok sorry again for that. I'll edit my question

Comment: Can you also include an example of what the merged object should look like?

Comment: @Spangle. Just did it. please check my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the steps which you need to follow.

- Create a new array for merged objects
- Iterate the array
- Find the item which you're looking for
- merge with the existing object to the filtered object
- append to new object
- done.

```js
let json = [{"id":191,"warehouse_id":24,"ingredient_id":65,"expiration_date":"2019-07-31","available_stocks":7,"ingredient":{"id":65,"name":"erg","SKU":"1000064","default_unit":{"id":26,"name":"Milliliter"},"purchase_price":50}},{"id":192,"warehouse_id":24,"ingredient_id":66,"expiration_date":"2019-09-18","available_stocks":33994,"ingredient":{"id":66,"name":"gvf","SKU":"1000065","default_unit":{"id":27,"name":"Gram"},"purchase_price":60}},{"id":193,"warehouse_id":24,"ingredient_id":67,"expiration_date":"2019-09-19","available_stocks":43996,"ingredient":{"id":67,"name":"fwefe","SKU":"1000066","default_unit":{"id":26,"name":"Milliliter"},"purchase_price":70}},{"id":52,"outlet_item_id":null,"warehouse_item_id":191,"ingredient_id":65,"quantity":7,"total_in_lowest":0,"stock_on_hand":0,"adjustment_price":0,"soh_total_in_lowest":0,"unit_price":50,"difference":0,"difference_in_lowest":0}];

// new array after merging the objects 
let desiredArray = [];
// iterate the array
let processedWarehouseItems = [];
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  let newObj = json[i]; // assign the each object if no filtered found in case
  // find the object based on your filter condition
  let fiteredObj = json.filter(
    e => e.id != json[i].id && e.warehouse_item_id === json[i].id
  );
  if (fiteredObj && fiteredObj.length) {
    // if object found
    processedWarehouseItems.push(fiteredObj[0].warehouse_item_id);
    newObj = { ...json[i], ...fiteredObj[0]
    }; // merge the objects and creates a new one
  }

  // check if the item is already merged in?
  if (processedWarehouseItems.indexOf(json[i].warehouse_item_id) === -1) {
    desiredArray.push(newObj); // push to the new array
  }
}
console.log(desiredArray)
```

Comment: This object should not appear because its already merge with the first object. {
    "id": 52,
    "outlet_item_id": null,
    "warehouse_item_id": 191,
    "ingredient_id": 65,
    "quantity": 7,
    "total_in_lowest": 0,
    "stock_on_hand": 0,
    "adjustment_price": 0,
    "soh_total_in_lowest": 0,
    "unit_price": 50,
    "difference": 0,
    "difference_in_lowest": 0
  }

Comment: get the processed `warehouse_item_id` in first step, and while pushing to the array check if the the id is already present then don't add the item to the newList.

Comment: Can you edit your code. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph changed!